# Replace branch statements by bit-shifting operations

Tags: algorithm, conditional-statements, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, branchless

I'm writing an image binarization algorithm which simply converts each pixel's luminance value (grayscale image) to a black or white. Currently the algorithm for binarizing each pixel is roughly this

```
if( grayscale[x] < thresholdValue)
{
bitonal[x] = 1;
}
```

(this is actually a simplification of the ACTUAL algorithm because the bitonal image is actually a bitpacked image (each array index holds 8 pixels) so I actually bitpack the 1 inside the current array index...but I don't think that changes my question.

What I'm attempting to do is to remove the need for the if-statement.

What I was thinking was to do something along the lines of this. Subtract the thresholdValue by the grayscale and then perform some bit manipulation trickery to clear out or shift bits such that if the result of `(grayscale[x]-threshold) is less than 0, I get a 0. otherwise I would get a 1` . If it's easier to do it the other way around `(if grayscale[x]-threshold < 0 + bitwise trickery get a 1, else get a 0)` that would also work... as long as I can get rid of the branch statements...any help appreciated..

Comment: Can you assume that bitonal[x] starts out as 0? Also, what language is this in? C?

Comment: Have you made sure that these calculations take place in code that is executed often enough to cause a performance impact?  Or do I have to post the micro-optimization lecture again?

Comment: @David.. where's your micro-optimization lecture it'd be nice for me to read..thank you

Comment: After your subtraction, isn't the sign bit of the result exactly what you want? You should be able to shift that into your bitpack, right?

Comment: Just do `bitonal[i] = (grayscale[i] >= threshold);`. Check the compiler's output, it might even implement that using your CPU's vector operations (or insane bit tricks). Check out http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html for a catalog of bitwise manipulations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bitonal[x] = (grayscale[x] < thresholdValue);`

Comment: Nice. If this was C, would it be guaranteed that the `<`-expression returns true as 1?

Comment: @divo, yes this is guaranteed by the standard.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I was looking for...thanks for the simple solution :D

Comment: The compiler probably optimizes your code to this code anyway behind the scenes though.. (and this may still have a branching instruction in it depending on the CPU)

Comment: Several of the answers involving bit shifting will also work, but this method is the fastest in gcc on x86, it's only 2 instructions (cmp, setl)

Comment: The compiler might use a branch opcode in its encoding/implementation this statement.

Comment: IIRC this is only defined in the C++ standard. Older C standards did only specified false as zero, but didn't specify true. That said, I do use this form in C++ programs.

Comment: @yar: thanks, I'm still evaluating other people's answers. with this one.

Comment: @phakahler:  The draft Ansi C standard (as described in K&R 2nd edition from 1988) does guarantee that the relational operators return 1 or 0.  You'd have to find a very old compiler to find one where this didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

If luminance is an 8-bit value, then you can have an array of 256 elements which contain either 0 or 1 (the first *threshold* elements of the array contain `1`, and the remaining elements contain `0`.

```
bitonal[x] = array[grayscale[x]];
```

Answer (score 4):

I've just been looking at similar stuff for a time-critical loop in my embedded app.
One interesting thing I found is that code like this

```
bit = (a<b);
```

still generates a branch instruction on my platform (TI F2812).  It seems the compiler has no direct way to move the status flag from a comparison into a register, so instead it generates something like

```
 temp_register =  0
 cmp a,b
 branch to label if LT
 temp_register = 1
label:
 bit = temp_register
```

However, the processor does have built-in max and min operators. Since branching is quite expensive, this code actually runs faster:

```
bit = min(max((b-a),0),1);
```

The result of `max` will only be non-zero if a < b.  And then the `min` will convert any non-zero to 1.

This is very processor specific, and may not apply at all on an X86.

Comment: Nice point about the TI-F2812. I do not believe that there's any branching on an x86, but that may not be true for ARM and other embedded platforms.

Comment: I tested this on an Intel Xeon and bitonal[x] = (grayscale[x] < thresholdValue); is 3 times faster than this method on that architecture.  Thanks for your input however.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you working with? Does the language have min/max functions? (C++ and Java for example both do) If the language does, that would be one way to elminate the if...eg Min(grayscale[x] < thresholdValue, 0)

Comment: I am using C++ And Mark Byers' solution works for me.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
bitonal[x] = ((grayscale[x] - thresholdValue) >> 31) xor 1;
```

Assuming your language doesn't equate boolean and integer values (as C and C++ do).

Comment: You're making the LSB the wrong polarity while preserving a bunch of garbage bits (unless it's unsigned math).

Comment: @phkahler - You're right, it does need to be unsigned math. This works in C#: `((uint)(grayscale - thresholdValue) >> 31) ^ 1` I was going to test it, but then the OP said he has using C++, so I just let it go. BTW-the disassembly is 3 instructions long--an eternity!--but has no jumps. :-)